# getting this error when i run the code to send message through Nexmo. message is sent but after that this error occurs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vonage

> Uncaught exceptioncallback is not a function {"stack":"TypeError:
>   callback is not a function\n    at callback
>   (/home/akkastech/backend-api/node_modules/nexmo/src/index.js:171:23)\n
>   at HttpClient.callback [as __parseResponse]
>   (/home/akkastech/backend-api/node_modules/nexmo/src/HttpClient.js:181:7)\n
>   at IncomingMessage.__parseResponse
>   (/home/akkastech/backend-api/node_modules/nexmo/src/HttpClient.js:93:16)\n
>   at emitNone (events.js:111:20)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit
>   (events.js:208:7)\n    at endReadableNT
>   (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)\n    at _combinedTickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)\n    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)"}

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you're passing something as a callback parameter that's not actually a function. It should look like this:

```
nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text, (err, responseData) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        if(responseData.messages[0]['status'] === "0") {
            console.log("Message sent successfully.");
        } else {
            console.log(`Message failed with error: ${responseData.messages[0]['error-text']}`);
        }
    }
})
```